# Custom shell script not working at boot with EC2 User Data in Launch Templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having trouble making a bash script run when adding it to the user data on an ec2 launch template. I've looked at suggestions and tried multiple approaches including AWS's suggestion using MIME multi-part in the script. I tried the #cloud-boothook directive but it only runs parts of my script on boot. The interesting part is that once the instance is booted I can run the script successfully by invoking it manually in /var/lib/cloud/instances/instance id/user-data.txt. I'm not sure what else to try so any help is appreciated. Below is my script.

```
#cloud-boothook

#!/bin/bash

apt-get update
pip install -I ansible==2.6.2
cd /tmp
wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.11.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -xvf go1.11.linux-amd64.tar.gz
mv go /usr/lib
apt-get -y install checkinstall build-essential
apt-get -y install libreadline6-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
cd /tmp
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/Python-2.7.15.tgz
tar -xvf Python-2.7.15.tgz
cd Python-2.7.15
./configure --prefix=/opt/python27myapp --enable-shared --enable-optimizations LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=/opt/python27myapp/lib
make
checkinstall --pkgname=python27myapp --pkgversion=2.7.15 --pkgrelease=0 --nodoc --default make install
cd /tmp
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
/opt/python27myapp/bin/python /tmp/get-pip.py
/opt/python27myapp/bin/pip install --progress-bar=off virtualenv


set -euo pipefail


DEPLOYER="myapp"
PYTHON_DIST_PACKAGES="/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"
PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES="lib/python2.7/site-packages"
ANSIBLE_VENV_PATH="/mnt/ansible-12f"
ANSIBLE_USER="ansible"
ANSIBLE_VERSION="2.6.2.0"
ANSIBLE_USER_HOME="/home/${ANSIBLE_USER}"
TF_PLAYBOOK_REPO="git@github.com:myorg/${DEPLOYER}.git"
TF_PLAYBOOK_GITREF="2019.8.0"
TF_PLAYBOOK_OPTIONS=""   # perhaps -vvvv
TF_PLAYBOOK_PATH="playbooks/twelve_factor/deploy.yml"
TF_APP_CONFIG_JSON="extra-vars.json"
TF_SCRATCH_DIR=$(mktemp -d -t tmp.XXXXXXXXXX)
TF_APP_CONFIG_PATH="${TF_SCRATCH_DIR}/config"
TF_ENVIRONMENT=""
EC2_INSTANCE_TAGS=""
CONFIG_BUCKET="databag-versions" 
REGION=$(curl -s  http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq -c -r .region)
app_user="myapp"


git-with-ssm-key()
{
  ssm_key="git_checkout_key"; shift
  ssh-agent bash -o pipefail -c '
    if aws ssm get-parameters \
         --region "'$REGION'" \
         --names "'$ssm_key'" \
         --with-decryption \
         --output text \
         --query Parameters[0].Value |
        ssh-add -k -
    then
      git "$@"
    else
      echo >&2 "ERROR: Failed to get or add key: '$ssm_key'"
      exit 1
    fi
  ' bash "$@"
}

#ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
# ============================================================================
cleanup() {
  rm -rf $TF_SCRATCH_DIR
}

final_steps() {
  cleanup
}
trap final_steps EXIT

# ============================================================================
install_packages() {
  apt-get -y install jq
}


check_for_aws_cli() {
  if ! aws help 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
    apt-get -y install awscli
  fi
  if ! aws help 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "The aws cli is not installed." 1>&2
    exit 1
  fi
  echo "Found: $(aws --version 2>&1)"
}

application_deployed() {
  [ -e "$TF_APP_HOME/current" ];
}

set_tf_app_home() {
  TF_APP_HOME="$(jq .deploy_env.deploy_to $TF_APP_CONFIG_PATH | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')"
}

set_ec2_instance_tags() {
  # We grab the EC2 tags of this instance.
  instance_id=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
  filters="Name=resource-id,Values=${instance_id}"
  EC2_INSTANCE_TAGS=$(aws ec2 describe-tags --region $REGION --filters "${filters}" | jq .Tags)
}

set_tf_environment() {
  # The tag whose Key is "Name" has the Value we want. Strip leading/trailing quotes.
  name=$(echo "$EC2_INSTANCE_TAGS" | jq '.[] | select(.Key == "Environment") | .Value')
  TF_ENVIRONMENT=$(echo $name | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
}

set_config_bucket() {
  case "$TF_ENVIRONMENT" in
    innovate|production|bolt|operations|blackhat)
      CONFIG_BUCKET="databag-versions"
      ;;
    *)
      CONFIG_BUCKET="databag-dev"
      ;;
  esac
}

retrieve_configuration_source() {
  # The tag whose Key is "Name" has the Value we want. Strip leading/trailing quotes.
  selectName='.[] | select(.Key == "Name") | .Value'
  name=$(echo "$EC2_INSTANCE_TAGS" | jq "$selectName" | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
  s3key="databags/$(echo $name | sed -e 's;-;/;g')"
  aws s3 cp s3://${CONFIG_BUCKET}/${s3key} ${TF_APP_CONFIG_PATH}
  set_git_ssh_key
  set_tf_app_home
}

install_python() {
  apt-get -y install python
  pip install virtualenv
  virtualenv $ANSIBLE_VENV_PATH
}

install_ansible() {
  source ${ANSIBLE_VENV_PATH}/bin/activate
  pip install ansible==${ANSIBLE_VERSION}
  echo "$PYTHON_DIST_PACKAGES" > "${ANSIBLE_VENV_PATH}/${PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES}/dist-packages.pth"
  # This will go wrong if the system python path changes.
  if [ ! -d "$PYTHON_DIST_PACKAGES" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: the system python packages location does not exist: $PYTHON_DIST_PACKAGES"
    exit 1
  fi
  # Having established a link between our vitualenv and the system python, we
  # can now install python-apt.
  pip install python-apt
}

add_playbook_user() {
  if ! getent group $ANSIBLE_USER > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    addgroup --system $ANSIBLE_USER
  fi
  if ! id -u $ANSIBLE_USER > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    adduser --system --home $ANSIBLE_USER_HOME --shell /bin/false \
            --ingroup $ANSIBLE_USER --disabled-password           \
            --gecos GECOS                                         \
            $ANSIBLE_USER
  fi
  if [ ! -d "$ANSIBLE_USER_HOME/.ssh" ]; then
    mkdir $ANSIBLE_USER_HOME/.ssh
  fi
  chown ${ANSIBLE_USER}:${ANSIBLE_USER} $ANSIBLE_USER_HOME/.ssh
  chmod 700 $ANSIBLE_USER_HOME/.ssh

  echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" > $ANSIBLE_USER_HOME/.ssh/config
  chown ${ANSIBLE_USER}:${ANSIBLE_USER} $ANSIBLE_USER_HOME/.ssh/config

  # echo ${GIT_SSH_KEY} > $ANSIBLE_USER_HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
  echo $GIT_SSH_KEY | sed -e "s/-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/&\n/"    -e "s/-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/\n&/"    -e "s/\S\{64\}/&\n/g" > $ANSIBLE_USER_HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
  chown ${ANSIBLE_USER}:${ANSIBLE_USER} $ANSIBLE_USER_HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
  chmod 600 $ANSIBLE_USER_HOME/.ssh/id_rsa

  if ! getent group $app_user > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    addgroup --system $app_user
  fi
  if ! id -u $app_user > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    adduser --system --home ${ANSIBLE_USER_HOME}/myapp --shell /bin/false \
            --ingroup $app_user --disabled-password           \
            --gecos GECOS                                         \
            $app_user
  fi
}

retrieve_playbook() {
  rm -rf "${ANSIBLE_USER_HOME}/${DEPLOYER}"
  (
    cd "${ANSIBLE_USER_HOME}"
    git-with-ssm-key /githubsshkeys/gitreader clone --branch "$TF_PLAYBOOK_GITREF" "$TF_PLAYBOOK_REPO"
  )
  chown -R ansible:ansible "${ANSIBLE_USER_HOME}/${DEPLOYER}"
}

patch_playbooks() {
  awk '/^- name:/ {f=0} /^- name: Establish SSH credentials/ {f=1} !f;' ${ANSIBLE_USER_HOME}/myapp/playbooks/twelve_factor/app_user.yml  > /tmp/temp_app_user.yml
  cp /tmp/temp_app_user.yml ${ANSIBLE_USER_HOME}/myapp/playbooks/twelve_factor/app_user.yml # temp file is necessary since awk can't edit in-place

  # remove the 'singleton' run operation... this isn't a singleton, and the playbook fails on the check to determine that.
  sed -i 's/^.*singleton.*$//' ${ANSIBLE_USER_HOME}/myapp/playbooks/twelve_factor/app.yml  

  # fix the "invalid ioctl" warning, which is non-breaking but creates ugly warnings in the log
  sed -i -e 's/mesg n .*true/tty -s \&\& mesg n/g' /root/.profile 

  # fix myapp user permissions in the /mnt/ansible-12f directories
  chown -R myapp:myapp ${ANSIBLE_VENV_PATH}

  # set up proper git SSH access for the ansible user
  echo -e "host github.com\n HostName github.com\n IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa\n User git" >> $ANSIBLE_USER_HOME/.ssh/config

  # set up the same git access for the myapp user
  if [ ! -d "/mnt/myapp/.ssh" ]; then
    mkdir -p /mnt/myapp/.ssh
  fi

  # ensure the directory will have the right permissions
  mkdir -p /mnt/myapp/releases
  cp ${ANSIBLE_USER_HOME}/.ssh/* /mnt/myapp/.ssh
  chown -R ${app_user}:${app_user} /mnt/myapp
}

set_git_ssh_key() {
  GIT_SSH_KEY="$(aws ssm get-parameters --region $REGION --names git_checkout_key --with-decryption --query Parameters[0].Value --output text)"
  ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
}

write_inventory() {
  IP_ADDRESS=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)
  cat - <<END_INVENTORY | sed -e 's/^ *//' > "${ANSIBLE_USER_HOME}/inventory"
  [${IP_ADDRESS}]
  ${IP_ADDRESS} ansible_python_interpreter=${ANSIBLE_VENV_PATH}/bin/python
  [linux]
  ${IP_ADDRESS}
  # This bizarre group name will never be used anywhere.
  # We need another group with an entry in it to avoid triggering
  # the cmd_singleton section.
  [12345_xx_%%%%_xxxx_]
  10.10.10.10
END_INVENTORY
}

# Located in the directory in which ansible-playbook is executed; it is
# automatically picked up as Ansible runs.
write_ansible_settings() {
  cat - <<END_SETTINGS | sed -e 's/^ *//' > "${ANSIBLE_USER_HOME}/ansible.cfg"
  [defaults]
  inventory      = /etc/ansible/hosts
  library        = /usr/local/opt/ansible/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules
  remote_tmp     = /tmp/.ansible-${USER}/tmp
  pattern        = *
  forks          = 5
  poll_interval  = 15
  transport      = smart
  gathering = implicit
  host_key_checking = False
  # SSH timeout
  timeout = 30
  # we ssh as user medidata, becoming the 12-factor user, so:
  # see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user
  allow_world_readable_tmpfiles = True
  ansible_managed = Ansible managed: {file} modified on %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S by {uid} on {host}
  action_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/action_plugins
  callback_plugins   = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/callback_plugins
  connection_plugins = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/connection_plugins
  lookup_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/lookup_plugins
  vars_plugins       = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/vars_plugins
  filter_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible_plugins/filter_plugins
  fact_caching = memory
  retry_files_enabled = False
  [ssh_connection]
  # We have sometimes an error raised: Timeout (32s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt
  # To avoid this, we make multiple attempts at the connection:
  retries = 5
  ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ServerAliveInterval=120
  control_path = %(directory)s/%%h-%%r
  pipelining = False
END_SETTINGS
}

write_deployment_config() {
  cat - <<END_SETTINGS > "${ANSIBLE_USER_HOME}/${TF_APP_CONFIG_JSON}"
END_SETTINGS
}

run_deployment() {
  write_inventory
  write_ansible_settings
  write_deployment_config
  (
    cd ${ANSIBLE_USER_HOME}
    ansible-playbook "${DEPLOYER}/${TF_PLAYBOOK_PATH}"      \
      -i ${ANSIBLE_USER_HOME}/inventory                               \
      "${DEPLOYER}/${TF_PLAYBOOK_PATH}"          \
      --connection=local                         \
      --extra-vars @${TF_APP_CONFIG_PATH}
      2> /tmp/ansible.err | tee /tmp/ansible.out
  )
}

# -----------------------------------------------------
# ---------------- Script Starts Here -----------------
# -----------------------------------------------------
install_packages  # do we need to check if packages already installed?
check_for_aws_cli
set_ec2_instance_tags
set_tf_environment
retrieve_configuration_source
if application_deployed; then
  echo "Application already deployed; taking no action"
else
  add_playbook_user
  install_python
  install_ansible
  retrieve_playbook
  patch_playbooks
  run_deployment
fi
chown -R ${app_user}:${app_user} /mnt/myapp/services
chown -R ${app_user}:${app_user} /etc/sv/myapp*
```

Comment: You can view the User Data script log in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`. It should give you a hint as to what problems are occurring, or where in the script it is stopping/failing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `sudo` before every command.

Also can you plz share the error you are getting?

Comment: This is incorrect. User Data scripts run as the `root` user.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing `set -euo pipefail` in the script.